# curl to wc3 validator not working?

Tags: curl, w3c, w3c-validation

when I run the following, i get a w3c page with upload options, as though nothing has been uploaded. curl seems to be putting it up though, so i'm at a loss as to what to even troubleshoot

```
dylan@MAJUSCULE:/opt/lampp/htdocs/dylanstestserver$ php index.php > test.html  && curl -F "uploaded_file=@index.php;type=text/html" http://validator.w3.org/ > results.html && firefox results.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 28874    0 26970  100  1904  55218   3898 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 76619
dylan@MAJUSCULE:/opt/lampp/htdocs/dylanstestserver$
```

Comment: did you solve the issue since?

Answer (score 1):

I think **http://validator.w3.org/** needs to be **http://validator.w3.org/check**

More info here:
http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html